# How to set console TTY1 to CP437?

Tags: console

When I do `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` there isn't the CP437, how can I enable it?
I've installed the `console-data` package, put the ACM cp437 on the `/etc/default/console-setup`, rebooted and run `setupcon` and run my application, but nothing happens.

Comment: Actually it's pretty clear. OP is trying to connect to a telnet service with codepage 437 (also known as Extended ASCII) which is not supported by Ubuntu.

Comment: @Ringtail I'm going to have to agree with user here. The question is clear and concise. It's unfortunate that it was closed. I'm trying to accomplish exactly this. :/